# How is the PVP soul reward calculated?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I wonder how the number of souls earned after killing a player in PVP are calculated.

- Does it depend on the number of souls owned by the killed player?
- Is the reward the same for the invader and the invaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Wiki](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/pvp-soul-value)

> The amount of souls awarded in PvP is a fixed amount based on your opponent's level. The amount they are carrying has no effect on what they drop, and is instead a percentage of the cost it took them to reach their current level (from their previous one). A level 100 player will drop some percentage of 13,545 souls, the cost of leveling up from level 99 to 100.
>
> **Rewards 10%**
>
> In most situations where an invader or hostile phantom kills another player, the invader will receive 10% of the leveling cost. This includes:
>
> - Defeating a host through a Cracked Red Eye Orb invasion.
> - Defeating a host as a Bell Keepers Invader.
> - Defeating a host as a Red Sign Soapstone summon.
> - Defeating a host as a Dragon Remnants summon.
> - Defeating a Red Phantom as a Blue Sentinels summon.
>
> Additionally, hosts will also only receive 10% in cases where the PvP is consensual for the host. This includes:
>
> - Defeating a Red Phantom summoned through a Red Sign Soapstone sign.
> - Defeating a Dragon Spirit summoned through a Dragon Eye sign.
> - Defeating a Grey Spirit summoned through the Rat King Covenant.
>
> **Rewards 37.5%**
>
> In most situations where a host defeats a hostile phantom who invaded their world without consent, the host is awarded 37.5% of the leveling cost. This includes:
>
> - Defeating a Bell Keepers invader.
> - Defeating a Cracked Red Eye Orb invader.
> - Defeating a Cracked Blue Eye Orb invader.
>
> This category also includes:
>
> - Defeating a Rat King Covenant host when summoned as a Grey Spirit.
>
> **Rewards Zero Souls**
>
> Killing a host when invading through the Cracked Blue Eye Orb awards the player with 0 souls. The Brotherhood of Blood and Blue Sentinels covenants also do not reward any souls when dueling through their arenas.

Comment: Perfect answer, thx !